# Appending Strings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I know this will be easy for someone. I need to combine objects to make one address. I dont know how to do it. I tried...

```
    NSString *agcstr = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"physstr"];
NSString *agccity = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"physcity"];
NSString *agcstate = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"physstate"];
NSString *agczip = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"physzip"];

dvController.agcaddress = [agcstr stringByAppendingString:@"\n"     stringByAppendingString:agccity stringByAppendingString:@", " stringByAppendingString:agczip];
```

which is completely wrong but I always at least attempt something :)

Comment: Well the way you do is absolutely right though it might seem weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
NSString *agcstr = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"physstr"];
NSString *agccity = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"physcity"];
NSString *agcstate = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"physstate"];
NSString *agczip = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"physzip"];

dvController.agcaddress = [[[[agcstr stringByAppendingString:@"\n"] stringByAppendingString:agccity] stringByAppendingString:@", "] stringByAppendingString:agczip];
```

Alternatively,

```
dvController.agcaddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@, %@", agcstr, agccity, agczip];
```

Comment: This is a really poor idea. You are creating and immediately throwing away three string objects in that last line, and it's difficult to read. taskinoor's suggestion for `stringWithFormat:` is much better.

Answer (score 3):

Try `stringWithFormat`

`dvController.agcaddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@, %@", agcstr, agccity, agcstate, agczip];`